# Filter for users on custom post type

Tags: user-registration

We have "Reviewer Register page" on front-end form.
There is a custom post type "Reviewers" to see reviewers lists.

When you register as a reviewer, a custom post is created with the reviewer name.

This works fine with front-end register form.

My problem is when you add "a reviewer" on back-end users page.
Add a user and give him/her a role "reviewer"

But I don't know how to add a post on a custom post type (Reviewers)

My front end form add a post on a custom post type (Reviewers). but Not back-end users menu

Is there any filter for handling register or login functions on back-end or anything related login/register?

we need to add a function when you add / change a user on back-end user page.

This is how we add the user information to custom post type ("reviewer") on FRONT END.

```
    if($edit) $args["ID"] = $edit->ID;

    $user_id = ($edit) ? wp_update_user($args) : wp_insert_user($args);



    if(!$edit && $kko_ut=='reviewer') wp_insert_post(Array(

        "post_title"=> sprintf("%s %s", $fields['first_name'], $fields['last_name'])

        , "post_content" => ""

        , "post_status" => "publish"

        , "post_author" => $user_id

        , "post_type" => "reviewer"

    ));
```

We need that it works when you add users on users page on BACK END as well.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is not clear. Please [edit] it to include more detail, as well as all relevant code.

Comment: is it better to make u understand? I don't have specific codes for it.

Comment: Where is that page coming from? What creates/registers the custom post type?

Comment: custom post type is that "reviewers". we created the register page.

Comment: I added register source for insert. please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code

```
do_action('user_register', $user_id);
add_action ('user_register', "test");
function test($user_id) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $role_of_user = $user->roles[0];
    if($role_of_user == 'your role'){
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'My post',
            'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => $user_id
        );
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    }
}
```

It will create a post when a user of `your defined role` is create by admin i.e from backend.

For profile update i.e if user role is update from some other role to `your defined role`

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );
```

Use [`profile_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) action and rest of the code same.

Comment: 1st of all, Thanks, so I added register code. please have a look.  add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

    function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
        // put wp_insert code here????
    }

Comment: oh I understand what you mean. I will try and let you know. thanks

Comment: I added at 1st line this.. global $user_id; (is it ok?) and works so well!! thanks